# Why is R reading UTF-8 header as text?

Tags: r, csv, utf-8, byte-order-mark, file-encodings

I saved an Excel table as text (*.txt). Unfortunately, Excel don't let me choose the encoding. So I need to open it in Notepad (which opens as ANSI) and save it as UTF-8. Then, when I read it in R:

```
data <- read.csv("my_file.txt",header=TRUE,sep="\t",encoding="UTF-8")
```

it shows the name of the first column beginning with "X.U.FEFF.". I know these are the bytes reserved to tell any program that the file is in UTF-8 format. So it shouldn't appear as text! Is this a bug? Or am I missing some option? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try it with the `read.csv` argument `check.names=FALSE`. Note that if you use this, you will not be able to directly reference columns with the `$` notation.

Comment: UTF-8 files are **not** supposed to contain a byte order mark, see [RFC 3629](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3629.txt) for explanation.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew. It works partially. The X.U.FEFF is gone, but I can't refer to the first column by name anymore (the others still work, though). I still think this is a bug to be solved in future versions of R.

Comment: You can refer to them by name if you put them in quotes, e.g., `yourdf$"first col"`

Comment: @Zack, I've seen some UTF-8 files with these first bytes, so I thought it was a rule. Not a big problem, as I can always rename the first column, just think it should be solved someday.

Comment: @Matthew, this second trick didn't work here.

Comment: I found a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24568056/rs-read-csv-prepending-1st-column-name-with-junk-text/24568505

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So I was going to give you instructions on how to manually open the file and check for and discard the BOM, but then I noticed this (in `?file`):

> As from R 3.0.0 the encoding "UTF-8-BOM" is accepted and will
>     remove a Byte Order Mark if present (which it often is for files
>     and webpages generated by Microsoft applications).

which means that if you have a sufficiently new R interpreter,

```
read.csv("my_file.txt", fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM", ...other args...)
```

should do what you want.

Comment: hmmmm almost there. Now the "X.U.FEFF." became "ï.."

Comment: That looks like the file isn't actually UTF-8. Is there any way you can show us a hex dump of the first line of the file?  (On most Unix systems, `head -1 my_file.txt | hexdump -C` will get you a nice hex dump, but I have no idea about a Windows equivalent.)

Comment: In DOS Prompt, debug does this. The first three bytes are EF BB BF. (I saved the file in Notepad 5.1 build 2600, Windows XP SP3, and it says the format is UTF-8). The rest of the line is the ASCII for the column names.

Comment: I need to see the dump for the entire line (or at least the entire first field, i.e. up to and including the first `09`), not just the first three bytes.

Comment: EF BB BF 43 4F 4C 45 43 41 4F 09

Comment: Huh. After stripping the BOM, the first field is all ASCII uppercase letters, which should go into a data frame colname just fine. Do you in fact have R 3.x?  This is starting to look like a bug in the interpreter.

Comment: Yes, I have R 3.0.1. I downloaded Notepad++, and it gives me the option to save with and without the BOM. It seems R just can't handle the BOM.

Answer (score 4):

most of the arguments in `read.csv` are dummy args -- including `fileEncoding`.

use `read.table` instead

```
 read.table("my_file.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t", fileEncoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: With read.table I get an error: "Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 9191 did not have 25 elements". My read comment is actually more complicated, it is: data <- read.table("my_file.txt",header=TRUE,sep="\t",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,strip.white=TRUE,encoding="UTF-8",quote="")

Comment: great!! Then it worked.  Now you just need to clean up your source file ;)   Open it up in a plain text editor (I like sublime text 3), get down to line 9191 and inspect it

Comment: Thanks, @Ricardo. I only needed the comment.char="". But now it behaves exactly the same as read.csv... :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue loading a csv file using either `read.csv` (with `encoding="UTF-87-BOM"`), `read.table` or `read_csv` from the `readr` package. None of these attempt proved successful.

I could definitely not work with the BOM tag because upon sub setting my data (using both approaches `subset()` or `df[df$var=="value",]`), the first row was not taken into account.

I finally found a workaround that made the BOM tag vanish. Using the `read.csv` function, I just defined a string vector for my column names in the argument `col.names = ...` . This works like a charm and I can subset my data without issues.

I use R Version 3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution from the comments:

Try it with the read.csv argument `check.names=FALSE`. Note that if you use this, you will not be able to directly reference columns with the `$` notation, unless you surround the name in quotes. For instance: `yourdf$"first col"`.